# Fork output with waitpid

Tags: fork, waitpid

```
int main()
{
    if(Fork() == 0)
    {
       printf("a");
    }
    else
    {
       printf("b");
       waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
    }

    printf("c");
    exit(0);
}
```

The above code asks what are the possible outputs?

I find that, acbc, abcc, bacc but answer includes bcac. How can bcac be an answer? Is parent process exits before child process created or sth. else? I confused, any explanations are welcome.

Thnx.

Comment: Is `Fork` supposed to be `fork`?

Comment: Ignore it, assume it is wrapped.

Comment: Can we assume the wrapper is semantically identical to a raw `fork`? (And if so, why is it wrapped?)

Comment: Yes, identical. It is the code from my textbook. It is wrapped for error control and error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only guarantee is that `waitpid` won't return (unless it's interrupted) until the child's status information is available. As soon as you call `exit(0)`, the 0 is available. So `waitpid` can return *before* the child's output is flushed.

POSIX says: "The wait() function shall suspend execution of the calling thread *until status information for one of the terminated child processes of the calling process is available*, or until delivery of a signal whose action is either to execute a signal-catching function or to terminate the process." (It also says *waitpid* is identical in this respect.)

I don't know of any actual platform where this happens and can only imagine it happening on an OS that emulates POSIX in user space and thus has some user space code to signal the parent that the child is terminating rather than using its actual termination to signal the parent. But it's permitted by the standards.

This is really obscure and I wonder if this is the expected rationale for that sequence. I can think of no other.

Comment: So it is actually because of output flushing delay? Parent process cannot exit before child is terminated?

Comment: The parent process can (in theory) exit as soon as the child's status information is available, which it is as soon as the child *calls* `exit`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is don't always trust textbooks!

From the [errata](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/errata.html):

> p. 772, Solution to Practice Problem 8.3. The sequence bcac is not
>   possible. Strike the second to last sentence. The last sentence should
>   be “There are three possible sequences: acbc, abcc, and bacc.” Please
>   see Web Aside ECF:GRAPHS on the Web Aside page for an example of the
>   process graph.